# Wordpress white screen

Tags: wordpress

I moved my wordpress site from one host account to another. **I keep my URL unchanged.** After that, my site is work fine - but only on front side. I cannot login to admin area - there is only blank white screen after i enter my username and password. Here is a brief detail what i have installed and what i try to do for now:

- front end is work just fine - mean that DB connection is ok
- login form is appear correctly. I even try to enter wrong username and/or password in order to check auth procedsure - it's ok for incorrect login. If credentials is correct - white blank screen.
- have very simple template - no fancy sliders, no sophisticated framework - "simply works core"
- have Better WP security installed - i try to delete plugin folder - no change
- try to clean/delete .htaccess - no change
- try to get manually a secret key from .htaccess and login with him - again white blank screen.
- trying to run wordpress in debug mode - no error messages. Also no errors form php in error.log (***edited at 28.10.2013***)

Please, if anyone have same or similar problem - i'll be very happy to resolve this. My blog is a long time active, i have a lot of posts and pages there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After few days of hard but unsuccess tryouts, i found a solution. It's drastic and not well explain what happen, but it worked for me - and hope for something else too. So:

1. rename wp-content\plugins diretory to __plugins - this will deactivate ALL plugins
2. rename .htaccess to .__htaccess - this will remove all url rewrite records
3. clean browser cache
4. login from wp-admin\
5. when try to access plugin list, a lot of messages appear - sayng for deactivating all plugins
6. restore plugins and htaccess to their original names
7. and finally - activate all needed plugins again

In conclusion - this does not answer the question why (even if URL is not change) this happen. It also not so pleasant if you have a lot of plugins - you must remember which of them is activated.

Thank you all, that problem is closed for me.

Comment: It works for me, once i renamed theme file also. Rest of the process works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

try change this on your wp-config.php to see if the wordpress dump any useful information about this white screen.

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

Replace that line with the following:

```
// Turns WordPress debugging on
define('WP_DEBUG', true);

// Tells WordPress to log everything to the /wp-content/debug.log file
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);

// Doesn't force the PHP 'display_errors' variable to be on
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);

// Hides errors from being displayed on-screen
@ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you. But unfortunately - this doesn't help. I forget to mention in my question that i already check for errors, and switch on debug mode. I edited by question. Sorry, i still hope for some help.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it.
I tried the following:

- define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');
- Change Plugins name
- Check white spaces
- Increase memory
- Change Theme
- Upload new wp-admin

All of them didn't work..

I downloaded wp-config with ftp and changed the encoding using notepad++ from utf8-BOM to just utf8

Answer (score 0):

A white screen only tells you that something has gone wrong. 
This can be anything. Speculating is just a waste of time.

Go and find the error.log of your webserver!
Then last lines of this file should tell you what went wrong.
When you don't understand it, you can ask again.

Comment: It's my mistake - i forget to write in question that i already check for errors - no error at all. I also clear error.log an try again - just to be sure - again no errors.