# Wordpress white screen, plugin development

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having a weird issue with a plugin I am developing.

When I try to activate the plugin on my client's server, everything becomes white and there are no error messages.

Locally I was able to:

- Activate the plugin on the newest wordpress version.
- Activate the plugin on the same wordpress version my client uses.
- Activate the plugin on a copy of my client's site (copy of wordpress and db backup)

On the server side, i did everything explained here:
[Wordpress white screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599443/wordpress-white-screen)

There are no errors in the error.log

I'm not sure what to do now, any hit of where to look at?

Comment: This happened to me before. After a massive spree of rancid hunting I found that there was a problem with either a deprecated function or an undefined function. No error was ever received. It had to do with upgrading to the latest wp install and a conflict with one of the plugins. Are you able to deactivate all plugins and import the db again? then enable them one by one till you get the white screen?

Comment: Yes, the problem still relies on my plugin... The weird thing is that locally, the plugin runs perfectly on both versions of wordpress (my client's and the latest wordpress), so I'm not sure if the issue relies on a deprecated function... still I will double check. The only difference is that the server is running PHP 5.4 and my local machine has 5.3.

Comment: Have you checked the differences between the two versions to make sure your plugin isn't relying on one of the faults: http://www.attackr.com/php-5-4-vs-5-3-difference-what-to-watch-out-for-when-coding-with-new-version/

Comment: what prints when you set WP_DEBUG to true?

Comment: There were some left overs from previous plugin causing problems in the posts table in the db.